# Squid3 fails to start on boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, startup, upstart, squid

Squid3 does not start automatically on boot, in some cases. I have start it manually with `sudo service squid3 start`.

Any reason why?

Comment: Did you check the logfiles for any errors on startup? /var/log/squid/cache.log should contain any startup-related errors. If you see something there and need help figuring out what it means, you can add parts of the logfile to your question by editing it, and someone here may be able to help further.

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` as well. For me, `squid3` was failing becase I have wrote `include /home/user/.squid` at the end of `/etc/squid3/squid.conf`, but my home dir was not accessible by `squid3`. I ended up putting my stuff into `/etc/squid3/squid.conf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a file (you need to be root to do it): **/etc/init/squid3.override** .

And put this inside it:

```
start on (net-device-up IFACE!=lo
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]
```

For more info referring overriding upstart conf files read here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/init.5.html

Answer (score 0):

Add to `/etc/rc.local`, its will automaticaly start.

```
# nano /etc/rc.local

sudo service squid3 start
exit 0
```

or ceck your configuration.

I use squid3 without problem

Visit http://plantpest.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/squid3-proxy-dalam-catatanku/

Translate : Indonesian to English